# not showing anything in toolbar android app

Tags: android, toolbar

i want to add items in toolbar but any item that adding, not showing in my app.
please help me to solve this

my app screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4rDB.jpg)

menu_map.xml is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.map.myzing.mapzing.MapActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/add_alarm"
    android:title="@string/action_addAlarm"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

a part of MapActivity:

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
private Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (servicesOK()) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        if (initMap()) {
            mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
            mLocationClient.connect();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "can not be connected!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_map, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    return true;
}
  }
```

in other activity this toolbar is correct but this activity is not correct and show toolbar without any items or title!!!

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do but you should get the toolbar view `id` after `setContentView` not before it.

Like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: thanks alot...My problem was solved with your solution :)))